# Why does a site fill in href of link after mouse over event?

Tags: html

I was doing test automation and stumbled upon a problem(I could not get the 'href' attribute of an anchor tag). It turned out that the 'href' attribute would remain being '#' unless I move my mouse over it.

It's obvious that this is done on purpose. So my question is why does the site do this? I cannot think of any scenario one would need to do this(my knowledge about web optimization is poor, though). Is it about SEO or web crawler?

Comment: Preventing robots from following links?

Comment: Those links are just some help pages and several external websites. What's the point of preventing robots from following them?